# How to do a backup in parallel?

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, database-backups

I am running a DB backup (SQL server) via Powershell. The problem is that I can run this script only for *one* DB every time. How can I run a backup on some databases in parallel? (In the end of the process, I need bak files as a result).

I read about multi threading in Powershell, but I'm not sure it's the 'best practice' in this case.

This is the BACKUP query the I use Powershell/cmd to run it (only for 1 db)..how can I run a backup for more than **one** database?

```
"BACKUP DATABASE [${db}] TO  DISK = N'${db_back_path1}\\${db}.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'${db} Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION\""BACKUP DATABASE [${db}] TO  DISK = N'${db_back_path1}\\${db}.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'${db} Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION\"
```

Thanks!

Comment: SQL is sequential; if you have a batch with multiple statements, each will be run one after the other. If you do need to do multiple statements at the same time you'll need multiple connections doing those operations at the same time.

Comment: You could use PowerShell background jobs to run multiple instances in parallel (i.e. Start-Job, Wait-Job, Receive-Job).